# Why do const lvalues bind differently from const rvalues given T&& and const T& overloads?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, universal-reference

For this code (available at http://ideone.com/Mo7fQr)

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T&) { std::cout << "const T& overload\n"; }

template<typename T>
void f(T&&) { std::cout << "T&& overload\n"; }

int main()
{
  const int x = 0;

  f(x);                 // calls const T& overload
  f(std::move(x));      // calls T&& overload
}
```

the first call to `f` (with an lvalue) calls the `const T&` overload, while the second call (with an rvalue) calls the `T&&` overload. At least that's what happens with gcc 4.8.1 and the most recent VC++ (VC12).

I think I understand why the second call resolves as it does: because the first template instantiates to taking a `const int&` parameter, while the second template instantiates to taking a `const int&&` parameter, and because the argument passed at the call site is an rvalue, it preferentially binds to the rvalue reference.  (I believe this is specified in the C++11 standard at 13.3.3.2/3 bullet 1 sub-bullet 4.)

But for the first call to `f`, both templates instantiate to taking a parameter of type `const int&`. So why is the first template preferred when a `const` lvalue is passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the same function template specialization can be generated from more than one declaration, the declarations are disambiguated using *partial ordering of function templates* as described in the C++11 standard §14.5.6.2 Partial ordering of function templates [temp.func.order]. The compiler determines which of the templates is the most specialized and prefers it.

In your example, the `const T&` overload of `f` is more specialized than the `T&&` overload. Intuitively, `T&&` can be deduced to anything that `const T&` can, but not vice versa, so `const T&` is more specific and therefore its function overload is more specialized.

Comment: How can `T const&` not match anything `T&&` can? Got an example? (I think it actually *can* match anything, but would require qualification-adjustment for some things, like non-const lvalues and rvalues. Also, for rvalues, `T&&` is preferred over `T const&`, so that's that.)

Comment: @Xeo e.g., `T const&` can't deduce `int&` or `int&&`. If you tried to call `f` with an `int&` parameter, the `f(const T&)` overload is specialized to `f(const int&)` - notably not `f(int&)` - and requires a conversion sequence `int&` -> `const int&`.

Comment: I replaced "match" with "be deduced to" in the answer, think it's a bit more clear.